# reuse contact form 7 submission on thank you page

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a page with Contact Form 7 forms.
After submiting a form the user get redirected to a thank you page.

I would like to allow that user to resend the form with the same values once again (without having to fill in form).

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided the fields in your form so I've just put in some random ones.

In short, you need to grab the values on send, so in the Additional Settings tab of your form, add this:

```
on_sent_ok: "var yourname = $('.wpcf7 input[name=your-name]').val();var youremail = $('.wpcf7 input[name=your-email]').val();location = '/thank-you/?yourname='+yourname+'&youremail='+youremail+'&cf7favorite=';"
```

And then you need to have your contact form get the value from the query string like this:

```
[text* your-name default:get]
```

The url query parameter will have to match the field name exactly for the above to work.

Comment: super! tnx a lot for that